# Making an OpenGLES 2.0 library using C++ for both Android and iOS

Tags: android, c++, ios, opengl-es

I'm looking to take an OpenGL based library that I created in C++ and convert it (or rewrite it) using OpenGL ES 2.0 and integrating it with Objective-C in XCode on my Mac and integrating it with Java in Eclipse on my PC to (almost) simultaneously create an app for both Android and iOS. I'd like to keep my library in C++ if possible and mainly use my PC for the development.
The only thing is, I can't seem to find anything online about importing the OpenGLES 2.0 framework onto my PC so I can start converting. I have found some nice examples of a library that is written using Objective-C++, but nothing of how to call anything OpenGLES-based in C++ using Java and the Android SDK. I know it's a complex question, but I definitely think it's possible. I just need to know where to start. Note that I have checked, and all of my functions that I'm using in OpenGL should be capable of being converted to OpenGLES 2.0 with little issues. (It's pretty basic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To develop on PC using OpenGL-ES, I'd recommend you to give a try to [ANGLE](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) which translates OpenGL-ES calls to Direct3D. It is pretty mature as it's used by Firefox and Chrome for WebGL, to work around OpenGL driver problems on Windows for some vendors.

For Android, you can take a look at *Android NDK* and [NVidia Tegra sample code](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack) that will just show you what you ask.

Comment: Thanks! Now I just need to find out best practices on making a C++ library that is easily integrated with both Objective-C and Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, but you can use OpenGL ES 2.0 in C/C++ code in both platforms - Android and iOS. No need to use Java or Objective-C for calling OpenGL functions. As long as you don't use vendor/hardware specific OpenGL extensions your drawing code can stay exactly same for both platforms.

Comment: I am aware that I can use C++ entirely to call OpenGL functions, but the issue I'm running into is finding a tutorial or book on using C++ to call OpenGL ES 2.0 in general. In fact, on my Mac I have the OpenGL ES 2.0 library included and that's working out fine, but I don't know how to import it in Eclipse OR Visual Studio using Java OR C++. More or less, I'm trying to include the libraries in those two programs, but I'm looking for the best way to do it.

Comment: Here's is a pretty good book on OpenGL ES: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321502795/